# Azure AD Security Group access to SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I created a new security group in Azure AD. Now I want to use this security group to get access to my SharePoint site.

But when I open up the SharePoint site collection I have got an 'access denied' error. I included the security group in the site collection as owner.

Is it possible to use Azure AD security groups to get access on SharePoint Online site collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
When you add a new group and add new users, the new users have to re-sign-in to geht the correct permissions.